# Is there a way to make AuthorizeAttribute respond with status code 403 Forbidden rather than a redirect?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, http-status-code-403, authorize-attribute

If the user is not logged in and they request an action marked `[Authorize]`, then the response is a redirect to the Account/LogOn action (status code 302 Found).

Is there a way to make the response be status code 403 Forbidden instead?

Comment: Is this for a REST interface?

Comment: @Chris: No, but out of curiosity why do you ask? I was writing an HttpPost action for which I simply wanted to forbid the request if the user was not logged in rather than redirecting to the LogOn action.

Comment: FYI - [Authorize] *does* send back a 403 Forbidden.  The FormsAuthenticationModule traps 403 responses and turns them into redirects to the login page.  If you're not using forms authentication, you may want to change the <authentication> section of Web.config to reflect this so that the FormsAuthenticationModule doesn't run this logic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create an action filter that inherits from `AuthorizeAttribute`. Then override this method:

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{ 
   Response.StatusCode = 403;
   Response.Status = "Forbidden";
   Response.StatusDescription = "Forbidden";
   Response.End();
   Response.Close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user is not logged in then the more appropriate status code is 401:Unauthorized.  This is what the AuthorizeAttribute returns by default.

FormsAuthenticationModule will catch this return code and convert it into the redirect.  If you can disable (or not even load it) then this will be returned to the caller.

Comment: This isn't an answer!